# Python script is not running on PowerShell

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I am currently learning Python from "Learn Python the Hard Way". But when I tried to execute my file, it don't run and return the same line as shown below. I have also changed environment variable.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the content of `ex1.py`. From your screenshot it looks like the script is run (you'd get an error if the Python interpreter couldn't be found in the PATH), but doesn't produce output.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what you prescribed: `python` itself runs Python prompt. To run a **python script**, use e.g.

```
& "path-to-script\scriptname.py"
```

or

```
python "path-to-script\scriptname.py"
```

You can omit double quotes if neither `path-to-script` nor `scriptname.py` contains a space or other `cmd` or `powershell` *poisonous* character(s).

To run a **`powershell` script**, use

```
.\scriptname.ps1
```

**Edit**: if your script is named `python` (it's possible however **not a good practice**) and placed in current working directory then you could use:

- to run python script: `.\python.py`
- to run powershell script: `.\python.ps1`